# How to display profiler on different domain

Tags: symfony

Symfony application works as middleware and behind it we have a legacy code.
Symfony works on subdomain.

On Symfony pages profiler works great but we need to show same page on legacy, I've already done with it, but profiler try to access localhost/_wdt/token, need to change only URL to a subdomain.

Don't know how to fix it, try to replace twig template with my own and define URL? Cannot present code because I'm thinking how to start with this issue.

Can someone have similar problem and fix it?

[Actual]
404 - Profiler not found
[Expected]
200 - Profiler shows

PS. I've edited base_js.html.twig code for Profiler and change code to use this:

```
function(xhr) {
                    if (xhr.status !== 0) {
                        var sfwdt = document.getElementById('sfwdt' + token);
                        console.log(token);
                        sfwdt.innerHTML = '\
                            <div class="sf-toolbarreset">\
                                <div class="sf-toolbar-icon"><svg width="26" height="28" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 26 28" enable-background="new 0 0 26 28" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M13 0C5.8 0 0 5.8 0 13c0 7.2 5.8 13 13 13c7.2 0 13-5.8 13-13C26 5.8 20.2 0 13 0z M20 7.5 c-0.6 0-1-0.3-1-0.9c0-0.2 0-0.4 0.2-0.6c0.1-0.3 0.2-0.3 0.2-0.4c0-0.3-0.5-0.4-0.7-0.4c-2 0.1-2.5 2.7-2.9 4.8l-0.2 1.1 c1.1 0.2 1.9 0 2.4-0.3c0.6-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.1-1.3C18 9.2 18.4 9 18.7 8.9c0.5 0 0.8 0.5 0.8 1c0 0.8-1.1 2-3.3 1.9 c-0.3 0-0.5 0-0.7-0.1L15 14.1c-0.4 1.7-0.9 4.1-2.6 6.2c-1.5 1.8-3.1 2.1-3.8 2.1c-1.3 0-2.1-0.6-2.2-1.6c0-0.9 0.8-1.4 1.3-1.4 c0.7 0 1.2 0.5 1.2 1.1c0 0.5-0.2 0.6-0.4 0.7c-0.1 0.1-0.3 0.2-0.3 0.4c0 0.1 0.1 0.3 0.4 0.3c0.5 0 0.9-0.3 1.2-0.5 c1.3-1 1.7-2.9 2.4-6.2l0.1-0.8c0.2-1.1 0.5-2.3 0.8-3.5c-0.9-0.7-1.4-1.5-2.6-1.8c-0.8-0.2-1.3 0-1.7 0.4C8.4 10 8.6 10.7 9 11.1 l0.7 0.7c0.8 0.9 1.3 1.7 1.1 2.7c-0.3 1.6-2.1 2.8-4.3 2.1c-1.9-0.6-2.2-1.9-2-2.7c0.2-0.6 0.7-0.8 1.2-0.6 c0.5 0.2 0.7 0.8 0.6 1.3c0 0.1 0 0.1-0.1 0.3C6 15 5.9 15.2 5.9 15.3c-0.1 0.4 0.4 0.7 0.8 0.8c0.8 0.3 1.7-0.2 1.9-0.9 c0.2-0.6-0.2-1.1-0.4-1.2l-0.8-0.9c-0.4-0.4-1.2-1.5-0.8-2.8c0.2-0.5 0.5-1 0.9-1.4c1-0.7 2-0.8 3-0.6c1.3 0.4 1.9 1.2 2.8 1.9 c0.5-1.3 1.1-2.6 2-3.8c0.9-1 2-1.7 3.3-1.8C20 4.8 21 5.4 21 6.3C21 6.7 20.8 7.5 20 7.5z"/></svg></div>\
                                <a href="http://subdomain{{ path("_profiler_home") }}"' + token + '>Open the web profiler.</a>\
                            </div>\
                        ';
                        sfwdt.setAttribute('class', 'sf-toolbar sf-error-toolbar');
                    }
                },
                { maxTries: 5 }
```

This could allow me to open profiler page due to CROS limitation of HTTP. Is this any way to override this template to use my own?

Comment: Tried with overriding templates but it works only on third party I think, so this method fails...

Comment: Anyone? Need help with this, not found any new ways to replace this template...